# How To convert .wav file into bytearray withought any change in quality of .wav in android?

Tags: android, web-services, arrays, type-conversion, wav

Somehow I'm creating the .wav file from the android device and storing it on my SD-card. Now I want to send that .wav file to a Java webservice.I need to do some processing on that .wav file in some java application. So what I need to do is send the wav file through webservice to my server where the java application is stored. So for that I need to know how to convert wave file to byte array without making any change in the wav file's quality?

I have done that with the .net as follows...

```
 byte[] byteArrayFile = File.ReadAllBytes("D:/Projects/ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1/bhavik.wav");
```

But I'm new to android. Can anyone help me out?

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this useful library

http://commons.apache.org/io/

File f = new File

byte[] data =  org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(f);

Comment: How can i Download those  org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils to my eclipse??

Answer (score 0):

Check this question [Convert wav audio format byte array to floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235016/convert-wav-audio-format-byte-array-to-floating-point)