# float [] to bytes array conversion for AudioTrack

Tags: java, android, audiotrack

I am using AudioTrack for playing through some float values.

code:

```
float[] audio_payload = getFloatValues();
final int length = audio_payload.length;

int PLAYER_MODE = AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM;
int PLAYER_STREAM_TYPE = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;
int PLAYER_FORMAT = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT;
int PLAYER_CONF = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO;

int PLAYER_SR = 44100;
AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(PLAYER_STREAM_TYPE, PLAYER_SR, PLAYER_CONF, PLAYER_FORMAT, audio_payload.length*4, PLAYER_MODE);
track.write(audio_payload, 0, length, AudioTrack.WRITE_NON_BLOCKING);
track.play();
```

My problem is in android version 20 or below the function, `track.write(float[], offset, lenghtInBytes, writeMode);` isnt supported.
[Android Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#write(java.nio.ByteBuffer,%2520int,%2520int))

How can I convert my float values to short or bytes array for playing as they are supported on Android API level 3 or above?

I tried converting my float array to short array but it didnt worked, After conversion my original audio was changed. Same happend when I tried converting float to byte array.

The project I am working on has native-lib, so any conversion between flooat to short or float to byte in C or Java would be helpful.

Shorts to Float code i used:

```
public static short floatToShort(float x) {
    if (x < Short.MIN_VALUE) {
        return Short.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    if (x > Short.MAX_VALUE) {
        return Short.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    return (short) Math.round(x);
}
```

float to bytes:

```
public static byte[] convertToByteArray(float value) {
      byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
      ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes.length);
      buffer.putFloat(value);
      return buffer.array();

  }
```

After conversion audio recorder wasn't playing audio, nor I could see any error

**Update**
Also Tried

```
private short [] floatArrayToShortArray(float [] array) {
    short [] payload = new short[array.length];
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        payload[i] = (short) ((short) array[i] * 32767);
    }
    return payload;

}
```

But the audioTrack is not able to play.

Comment: Maybe you could just reverse the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235016/convert-wav-audio-format-byte-array-to-floating-point)? (which converts `byte`s to `floats`)

Comment: _"I tried converting my float array to short array but it didnt worked"_ Since you haven't shown us what you tried we have no way of knowing what you did wrong.

Comment: Well, the `putFloat` approach is of no use since that stores the floating point value as-is without any conversion. For example, `putFloat(0.5f)` would store the four bytes `0x3f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00`. What you need to do is go through each floating-point sample and convert them from whatever range they're in (I assume -1.0..+1.0) into a `short` in the range -32768..+32767.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael any relevant short piece of code or example?

Comment: Write a loop that multiplies each value by 32767 and casts the result to a `short`. Maybe there are more efficient solutions, but that should work as a starting point.

Comment: @Michael

Check updated.

Comment: _"the audioTrack is not able to play"_ is not a very meaningful problem description. We don't know that it has anything to do with the float to short conversion (which is what this question was about). First verify that you can play a known good waveform in `short` format. Then verify that your floating-point data is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to convert the `Float` to PCM16 short within such method:

```
/**
 * Used to convert Float to PCM16 short byte array.
 */
private val convertBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).apply {
    order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
}

/**
 * Converts Float to PCM16 short byte buffer.
 * @param value Float value to convert
 * @return PCM16 short byte array from Float value
 */
private fun floatToPcm16(value: Float): ByteArray {
    convertBuffer.clear()
    convertBuffer.putShort((value * 32768F).toShort())
    return convertBuffer.array()
}
```